# Why doesn't a console loaded script have access to the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I added a script to the DOM using

```
// in the console of facebook.com

var test = document.createElement('script');
test.src = "foo";
document.head.appendChild(test);
```

but the script has no access to the DOM.

Does this have to do with the same origin policy?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't have access to the DOM?

Comment: I mean it doesn't find anything, it detected no div elements when there are in fact many div elements.

Comment: what are you actually using for src? a full url ending in .js?

Comment: @johnnysirocco: “it doesn't find anything”. *What* doesn’t find anything? The code you’ve provided adds `<script src="facebook.com/foo"></script>` to the page. Because facebook.com/foo doesn’t exist, nothing will happen.

Comment: foo is just a place holder....according to my script their are no set z-indexes on the land page for facebook.

Comment: Firefox is highlighting it red and calling it mixed content.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent): "If the HTTPS page includes content retrieved through regular, cleartext HTTP, then the connection is only partially encrypted: the unencrypted content is accessible to sniffers and can be modified by man-in-the-middle attackers, and therefore the connection is not safeguarded anymore. When a webpage exhibits this behavior, it is called a mixed content page... **Starting in Firefox 23, mixed active content is blocked by default**..."

Comment: doesn't Facebook have some sort of real-time linter?

Comment: @johnnysirocco I would expect that the HTTP script would not be allowed to run at all.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your *actual* scripts, both in the console, and the script file you load in? Please also share any error messages you see. That could allow people to solve your problem, instead of guessing.

Comment: I think the issue, is that Facebook has no z-indices set, and hence my tool did not find anything.  Acceess seems to be fine.  I am pre-FF23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution to add JQuery:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```